# Upgrading laptop keyboard to backlit one

Tags: laptop, keyboard, upgrade

I have a Dell Vostro 3450 laptop, which supports backlit keyboards. My laptop was bought with a simple, non-backlit keyboard. If I buy a backlit replacement keyboard, will it work right away, or is such upgrade difficult/not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backlit replacement keyboard is an optional component to the Dell Vostro 3450 laptop. It will work right away.

To use the backlit feature, press <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

You may need to install or update to the latest [QuickSet application](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/uk/en/ukbsdt1/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=8HJ39&c=uk&l=en&cs=ukbsdt1&s=bsd) from Dell to have windows properly recognize the hardware.

---

### Useful:

YouTube - [How Do I Enable the Backlit Keyboard?](http://youtu.be/hyb-rBdo5Js)

YouTube - [Laptop Keyboard Replacement](http://youtu.be/9x5SF_NFsw4)