# Add a backlit keyboard to Lenovo T430

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop

There is a related question here
[Upgrading laptop keyboard to backlit one](https://superuser.com/questions/459517/upgrading-laptop-keyboard-to-backlit-one)

My question is different than that because Lenovo T430 has an LED by the web cam. I know I can buy a backlit keyboard and add replace it myself. But when I turn on the backlit keyboard using Fn+Space (which is the same shortcut for that LED light I just mentioned), will the laptop automatically detect that there is a backlit keyboard in place now and turn it on? Also also how will that preexisting LED behave? I would not want it to turn on.

Answer (score 1):

I have a t430  with backlit keyboard.  Fn+spacebar toggles through two levels of backlit keyboard and the third press lights the LED by webcam.

I have a second T430 without the backlit keyboard so every other press of Fn+Spacebar toggles between the LED (by webcam) on and off.

I have added a backlit keyboard to that second T430 and the backlight doesn't come on so there must be something needed (BIOS setting?) to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the keyboard it is supposed to then allow the FN + Space combo to cycle through sequence as follows: Off > Keyboard-only dim > Keyboard-only bright > LED lid light only > repeat to Off.

Comment: This does not completely answer the original question, which asked about whether the LED keyboard commands will affect the LED for the web cam.

Comment: I just got a t430 and it ONLY has the LED lit light....it just toggles on/off. Wtf?? Are there multiple versions of the t430?

Answer (score 0):

For those who want permanent keyboard backlit beside SW solution,

there is very simple HW possibility to bridge LED supply

for PWR Button illumination with Backlit PWR supply pin,

The pins position is very efective, they are next to one on keyboard terminal.

Described possibility bellow is targeted for Thinkpad T530 / T530i / T430 / T430s

/ X230 / W530 , but solution should be very similar for huge number of LENOVO

series according idetnical HW usage ...

PWR LED pin 23 and BL PWR pin 25. Both of them are GPIOs  so dont wary about

sufficient or excessive currents. Typical Voltage for GPIOs is 3,3V.

Backlit supply becomes from GPIO153/LED2 - U23C (ic2 MEC1619 )

and PWR LED from LED1/GPIO157 - U23B (ic1 MEC1619 )

Its possible to realize bridge directly on Keyboard or on the laptop MB ...

MBs bridge gives possibility to get unrestricted voltage bypassing

the resistor R13 220 Ohm 5% 1005_1/16w ...

This bridge gives interesting ( permanent ) backlit behaviour

without any programming but depending on PWR LED illumination .... :-)